# Remove disabled attribute to submit button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-input

EDIT:
Thank you so much for your help! I also needed to target the div in which my modal lives so like:

`$('#message').on('input', '#createPostTitle, #createPostDescription, #createPostPrice', function(){ if($('#createPostTitle').val() != '' && $('#createPostDescription').val()!='' && $('#createPostPrice').val()!='') { $('#createPostSubmitButton').removeAttr("disabled"); }`

Leaving it here in case someone runs into the same issue!

---

I found some solutions to my issue but none of them worked for me. Apologies in advance for the redundancy.
I have created a modal that is triggered via a link in the header.
Once opened, the modal is presented with a disabled button that should be accessible once the first three fields are filled. I have simply tried to removed the attribute once the fields are completed but it simply doesn't work.

Here is the HTML and function.

The div that contains the link that opens the form is called "#message".

Thanks in advance

```js
$('#createPostTitle','#createPostDescription','#createPostPrice').on("input", function(){
  if($('#createPostTitle').val() != '' && $('#createPostDescription').val()!='' && $('#createPostPrice').val()!='') {
    $('#createPostSubmitButton').removeAttr("disabled");
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="createPostModal" aria-hidden="true">  
<form class="newPostForm">  
<div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 id="titleAlert">Create New Post</h5>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostTitle">Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostTitle" required>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostDescription">Description</label>
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostDescription" required></textarea>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostPrice">Price</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostPrice" required>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostLocation">Location</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="optional" id="createPostLocation">
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostWillDeliver">Will Deliver</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="createPostWillDeliver">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="createPostSubmitButton" disabled>Submit</button>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below, your error was in the usage of the `jQuery` selectors. So instead of:

```
$('#createPostTitle','#createPostDescription','#createPostPrice')
```

you need to write

```
$('#createPostTitle, #createPostDescription, #createPostPrice')
```

```js
$('#createPostTitle, #createPostDescription, #createPostPrice').on("input", function() {
  if ($('#createPostTitle').val() != '' && $('#createPostDescription').val() != '' && $('#createPostPrice').val() != '') {
    $('#createPostSubmitButton').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="newPostForm">
  <div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 id="titleAlert">Create New Post</h5>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="createPostTitle">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostTitle" required>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="createPostDescription">Description</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostDescription" required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="createPostPrice">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostPrice" required>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="createPostLocation">Location</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="optional" id="createPostLocation">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="createPostWillDeliver">Will Deliver</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="createPostWillDeliver">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="createPostSubmitButton" disabled>Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `on.("input")` selector is incorrect. Instead of separate strings, make it one, comma separated string.

```js
$('#createPostTitle, #createPostDescription, #createPostPrice').on("input", function(){

  if($('#createPostTitle').val() != '' && $('#createPostDescription').val()!='' && $('#createPostPrice').val()!='') {
    $('#createPostSubmitButton').removeAttr("disabled");
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="createPostModal" aria-hidden="true">  
<form class="newPostForm">  
<div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 id="titleAlert">Create New Post</h5>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostTitle">Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostTitle" required>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostDescription">Description</label>
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostDescription" required></textarea>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostPrice">Price</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="required" id="createPostPrice" required>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostLocation">Location</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="optional" id="createPostLocation">
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="createPostWillDeliver">Will Deliver</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="createPostWillDeliver">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="createPostSubmitButton" disabled>Submit</button>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```